# Display Certain Value in a Column oracle SQL

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Please Find the Sample Data below and Scenario

```
with data_1 as (
select 'Book' as object,'Long-Ruled' as Type,20 as Amount from dual
union
select 'Book' as object,'Short-Ruled' as Type,30 as Amount from dual
union
select 'Book' as object,'All Type' as Type,5 as Amount from dual
union
select 'Pen' as object,'Fountain' as Type,55 as Amount from dual
union
select 'Pen' as object,'All Type' as Type,100 as Amount from dual
)
```

I want my Output to be as in the attached image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1i9yU.png)

```
Object  Type        Amount  Certain_Amount
Book    Long-Ruled  20        5
Book    Short-Ruled 30        5
Book    All Type    5         5
Pen     Fountain    55       100
Pen    All Type    100       100
```

I want to add new Column "Certain Amount " that shows that "All Type" Amount in it .

I tried the Below Query.

```
select object,type,amount,sum(sub) over (partition by object) as certain_amount from
(
select object,type,amount,case when type not like 'All Type' then 0 else amount end as sub from data_1
)
```

i can achieve the required output from above query.is their a simple way to do it single query .thanks

Answer (score 0):

after posting the question i got the answer

select object,type,amount,sum(case when type not like 'All Type' then 0 else amount end ) over (partition by object) as sub from data_1